# How to move AtomicI64 as function parameter in thread::spawn()

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust and solving some https://projecteuler.net/ problems. So one function runs slow, and I want to run this function in parallel. I want to give counter to all functions and after processing function check if true (optimized_parallel returns bool).

```
pub fn parallel_comput() {

let  counter = AtomicI64::new(1);

loop {
    let first_thread = thread::Builder::new()
        .name("first_thread".to_string())
        .spawn( || optimized_parallel(counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst)));
    let second_thread = thread::Builder::new()
        .name("sec_thread".to_string())
        .spawn( || optimized_parallel(counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst)));
    if first_thread.is_ok() || second_thread.is_ok() {
        return;
    }
}
```

}

But after running this code i have an
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Kvt.png):

Thanks for help)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please never post screenshots of text. Instead copy paste the text into the question.

Comment: @PiRocks as KaiJ explained, the suggestion is probably not what the OP wants as it will create multiple counters and the primary one won't be incremented.

Comment: Managing shared state yourself is probably not the best way to solve your problem. You didn't provide enough information in the question to really say this for sure, but you most likely can use [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/1.5.0/rayon/) to parallelise your computation, without the cognitive overhead of orchestrating threads yourself.

Comment: @PiRocks Sorry, I tried to copy text but formatting was broken, so i decide to add a screenshot

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks for advice. I'll try this lib, it can be good solution for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring because spawned threads can outlive the current scope, and so they can't borrow values from the current scope. You can see that [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) takes a `'static` closure.

Crossbeam's [`scope`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) function allows you to spawn non-`'static` threads by making sure that all threads will complete before exiting the function. Alternatively, you can use an `Arc` which shares the value without lifetimes:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

let counter = Arc::new(AtomicI64::new(1));

loop {
    let first_thread = thread::Builder::new()
        .name("first_thread".to_string())
        .spawn({
            let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
            move || optimized_parallel(counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst))
        });
    let second_thread = thread::Builder::new()
        .name("sec_thread".to_string())
        .spawn({
            let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
            move || optimized_parallel(counter.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst))
        });
    if first_thread.is_ok() || second_thread.is_ok() {
        return;
    }
}
```

`Arc` is slightly less performant than `scope`, but is in the standard library and so doesn't need any dependencies.

Comment: Alternatively, make `counter` a global using something like `lazy_static`.